# UDL file for creation a connection string

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-string

I am going to use UDL file to create connection.
Is there any difference between UDL file with oracle connection string and MS SQL Server connection string?
Can I use:

```
DbConnection con = new DbConnection("File Name="+Server.MapPath("\\Conn.udl"));
```

for both type of connection - oracle and microsoft database? and what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - i have testet it many times with SQL 2000/5/8 and Oracle (9i and 10g)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with UDL file will work, but there is no ctor for DbConnection, you have to use the specific implementation like OleDbConnection for OLE DB connectivity (except MS ODBC driver, OdbcConnection fails to open connection until DSN is explicitly set).